# Unity - Buttons won't highlight on change

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I setup a small menu with 4 buttons. When I start the scene the first button gets selected by script and is shown highlighted. Now I can move through the menu with the keyboard and every button works as it should, but the first button stays highlighted and when I select another button it doesn't get highlighted.

The current UI menu is the fourth one in my game and every other menu works just fine and I made this menu the same way like the others. But there has to be something I'm missing. Maybe this sound familiar to someone?

The buttons are setup correctly and every button has it's highlight color set. I tryed to set the first selected button with the event system in the inspector, but that doesn't change anything.

[image]

Comment: Would be great if you could show the code you use to select the button that you want to get highlighted but which doesn't.

Comment: I only use code to preselect the first button on start with myButton.Select() where myButton is of type UI.Button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem by myself. I duplicated the first button for the others and I forgot to change the target graphic in the button component.